# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
Frame(w, width = 427, height = 250, bg = '#272727').place(x = 0, y = 0)

label1 = Label(w, text = 'APP', fg = 'white', bg = '#272727').place(x = 0, y = 0)

label1.configure(font =("Game of Squids", 24,"bold"))
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
import tkinter as tk

w = tk.Tk()
tk.Frame(w, width = 427, height = 250, bg = '#272727').place(x = 0, y = 0) 
label1 = tk.Label(w, text = 'APP', fg= 'white', bg = '#272727')
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0) 
label1.config(font =("Game of Squids", 24,"bold"))

w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, .place() method doesn't return anything!

You should edit your code like this:

```
Frame(w, width = 427, height = 250, bg = '#272727').place(x = 0, y = 0)
label1 = Label(w, text = 'APP', fg = 'white', bg = '#272727')
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)
label1.configure(font =("Game of Squids", 24,"bold"))
```